# Given a line of two points, constrict the drawing of the next line within a certain angle.

Tags: geometry, angle

Presume I have a line made up of two points on a 2D plane. We'll call the line AB, and it is drawn randomly with a random length and angle to the global X axis. I then need to draw line BC, which spans from the end of line AB and adds a new point: 'C'. This BC line needs to be constricted to a certain angle. The actual angle doesn't matter.

[Consider this crude diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP32A.jpg)

The green area represents the ambiguous area in which the next point can be drawn. Note that the length of the line should also be variable (i.e. the distance of point C from B).

EDIT: To clear things up, the allowed angle area should be influenced by the angle of the AB line against the global X

[See crude diagram 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NboMX.jpg)

In short, the question is. How would I mathematically define an "allowed drawing space" for point C so it can be any variable length and be constrained within the green area. The green area should be influenced by the line AB, based on its angle to the global X.

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is your question ? How to express coordinates $(x_C,y_C)$ of point $C$ ? If such is the case, let $(x_B,y_B)$ the coordinates of point $B$, and take $x_C=x_B+$ any positive number,  $y_C=y_B+$ any positive number.... (if your green axes are always like on your figure ...) If this is a too particular case, draw another figure, less particular.

Comment: Close! I will draw another diagram explaining further.

Comment: Edited. @JeanMarie

Comment: Do you mean that the green limits together with line AB always make a shape like letter "Y" with a fixed symmetrical opening of the arms of this "Y" letter ?

Comment: Yep! To give some context, it's because I want to make random smooth-ish lines in a program. This will make it so they don't ever generate really harsh sharp corners, but rather smooth out a lot nicer.

Comment: I understand now clearly your purpose. I will give you an answer this evening (it's 10:30 a.m. CET for me).

Comment: I think I may have figured something out, but I've had no time to work on it today, so I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your objective, i.e., build a rather smooth broken line without sudden orientation changes, here is an algorithm that performs the work:

$\text{Initialisation} \ : \ \theta_0=0, \ x_0=0, \ y_0=0, \ n=500, \ a=0.2$

$\text{Repeat for } \ k=1 \ \text{to} \ n:$

$\begin{array}{l}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{AngleVariation = (2*random - 1)}*a*\pi \\  
\ \ \ \ \ \ \theta_{k+1} = \theta_{k} + \text{AngleVariation} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ r_{k} = \text{random} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ x_{k+1} = x_{k} + r_{k}*\cos(\theta_{k}) \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ y_{k+1} = y_{k} + r_{k}*\sin(\theta_{k}) \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{plot segment line from point} (x_{k}, y_{k}) \ \text{to point} \
 (x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})
\end{array}$

*Explanation :*

- $a$, set here to $0.2$, is an adjustable parameter controlling the aperture of the angle.
- "random" is a uniformly distributed number with value between $0$ and $1$. Every time it's called, it is a new random number that is generated. In this way "2*random - 1" is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$.
- the choice of the number of line segments $n=500$ is, of course, arbitrary.
- $\pi$ (in radians) is the same as $180°$ (in degrees).

*Illustration :*

I have programmed the algorithm with Matlab. Here are two results, the first one with $a=0.1$, the second one with $a=0.3$, showing the influence of this parameter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll put it into practice a little later tonight and accept your answer if it meets my needs, or if it gets me close enough to my needs. Also thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have added two graphics.

Comment: Oh dude that's awesome. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much. You didn't have to add the graphs, but they really do show that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Thanks for your thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to determine the equations of the green lines, for example $y = ax+b$ for the lower line and $y = cx+d$ for the upper line, where the slopes $a$ and $c$ can be found from the angle of line AB and the allowable angle between AB and BC and then the intercepts $b$ and $d$ would be found to satisfy each line so the intersect point B. Then the representation of the allowable point would be in the form $ax+b < y < cx+d$ or as the system $ax+b < y$, $y < cx+d$. Any point that satisfies both inequalities simultaneously would work.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments this is only true if both lines go to the left or both lines go to the right. If one green line goes to the left and the other to the right or if either (or both) is vertical then my solution is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, but it's erroneous if slopes $a$ and $b$ don't have the same sign.

Comment: @JeanMarie may be right, but I don't think I'll ever meet a use case where I'll need to do this for differently signed slopes. I think you hit the nail on the head from my limited understanding of what you wrote. Would you be so kind as to give a visual example? Be it a chain of reasoning with steps provided or actual diagrams haha.

Comment: I do see an error in my logic, but not when they have slopes of different signs. If for example one line is up to the left and the other is down to the left it still works. If one green line goes to the left and the other to the right then my solution is invalid. For that matter if one or both green lines are vertical it doesn't work. I will leave my answer here but will make a note.

Comment: @Ravenex Diagram 2.0 displays a case where the limit (green) lines have slopes with different signs.

Comment: @JeanMarie I understand that in that case the resulting Y would have to be greater than the equation of both lines, but if both lines pointed to the right one with positive slope, one with negative, my solution would hold. The problem isn't the sign of the slope it's a left/right problem.